# React form's defaultValue updates on page reload when a unique key is assigned to it but it doesn't when key is not there

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

I am currently working on edit functionality using react form and want the data in the form fields to be pre-populated with the props value and for that I have assigned it to `defaultValue` in the form fields.

But the problem I came across while doing this is my `defaultValues` flush out on page reload. I tried finding a solution for it and came across few hacks to make the dom in sync with defaultValue. One of which was assigning a key to the wrapper component of the input field.

What is the reason for this behaviour of defaultValue?

Could anyone please help me figure out why the form field behaves like that? Here's the related snippet:

```
 var title = this.props.post.title;
 return (
    <form
      onSubmit={
        postId ? this.handleUpdate.bind(this) : 
        this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
      }
    >
      <h3>
        {postId ? "Edit post" : "Create a New Post"}
      </h3>
      <FormGroup key={title} controlId="formControlsText">
        <ControlLabel>Title</ControlLabel>
        <FormControl
          type="text"
          inputRef={ref => {
            this.title = ref;
          }}
          placeholder="Enter title"
          defaultValue={title}
        />
      </FormGroup>
     </form>
    )
```

Comment: Your title is reflecting your props. But if you don't save the title to the store, when you refresh the store isn't saved. Does that sound accurate? I'm trying to understand

Comment: Yes,the title is saved only on clicking submit button,until then props value is same as previous one.Then why isn't it shown as default title?

Comment: Im sorry, I suppose I dont fully understand the issue. props value is same as previous one? if youre able to list out the exact thing you need then I can help you write that up